# Post object with many recipients

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I have three models : user, houses and a post.

I am trying to assign a post to one author and mutliple recipients, but I do not know how to do it. 
I reckon it may have to do with relationships between tables...

These are my models

```
lettings = db.Table('lettings',
    db.Column('tenant_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id')),
    db.Column('property_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('house.id'))
)

class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'user'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(64), index=True, unique=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), index=True, unique=True)
    password_hash = db.Column(db.String(128))
    lettings = db.relationship("Houses",secondary=lettings,lazy="dynamic", backref=db.backref("tenants",lazy="dynamic"))

    posts_sent = db.relationship('Post',
                                    foreign_keys='Post.sender_id',
                                    backref='author', lazy='dynamic')
    posts_received = db.relationship('Post',
                                        foreign_keys='Post.recipient_id',
                                        backref='recipient', lazy='dynamic')
    last_post_read_time = db.Column(db.DateTime)

    def haslived(self,house):
       if not self.isliving(house):
        self.lettings.append(house)

    def unlived(self, house):
        if self.isliving(house):
            self.lettings.remove(house)

    def isliving(self, house):
        return self.lettings.filter_by(id=house.id).first()


class Post(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'post'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(32))
    body = db.Column(db.String(140))
    timestamp = db.Column(db.DateTime, index=True, default=datetime.utcnow)
    sender_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
    recipient_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
    house_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('house.id'))
    __searchable__= ['body']

    def __repr__(self):

        return '<Post {}>'.format(self.body)

class Houses(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'house'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True,index=True)    
    address = db.Column(db.String(120))
    postcode = db.Column(db.String(120),index=True)
    licence_holder = db.Column(db.String(140),index=True)    
    __searchable__=['address']
    posts = db.relationship('Post', backref='letting', lazy='dynamic')

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<House {}>'.format(self.address)
```

And this is my routes code snippet:

```
@bp.route('/house/<address>/ask',methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def ask(address):
    house = Houses.query.filter_by(address=address).first_or_404()
    form = PostForm()
    if form.submit.data and form.validate_on_submit():
        post = Post(body=form.body.data,title=form.title.data,author=current_user,letting=house,recipient={I do not know what to write here})
        db.session.add(post)
        db.session.commit()
        flash('Your post is now live!')
        return redirect(url_for('main.house', address=house.address))
    return render_template('ask.html', title='Ask a question about {}'.format(house.address),form=form,house=house)
```

My objective is to create a post object which will have only one sender but multiple recipients. 
Thank you for your help.

Comment: you should have something similar to table `lettings` - and then you can have many rows with the same `post_id` but every row will have different `recipient_id`

Comment: see flask-sqlalchemy [one-to-many-relationships / many-to-many relationships](https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/models/#one-to-many-relationships)

Comment: I had a seperate table Letting with user id, house id and address id, but then i needed the similiar relation "from other side", so as if table "tenants"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, as somebody above correctly pointed out, this can be done using many-to-many relationship from SQLalchemy.
I got the answer myself, that's how i modified the code: 
My models:

```
lettings = db.Table('lettings',
    db.Column('tenant_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id')),
    db.Column('property_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('house.id'))
)

class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'user'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(64), index=True, unique=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), index=True, unique=True)
    password_hash = db.Column(db.String(128))
    reviews = db.relationship('Review', backref='author', lazy='dynamic')
    checklists = db.relationship('Checklist', backref='author', lazy='dynamic')
    about_me = db.Column(db.String(140))
    lettings = db.relationship("Houses",secondary=lettings,lazy="dynamic", backref=db.backref("tenants",lazy="dynamic"))
    posts_sent = db.relationship('Post',
                                    foreign_keys='Post.sender_id',
                                    backref='author', lazy='dynamic')
    last_post_read_time = db.Column(db.DateTime)

    def new_posts(self):
        last_read_time = self.last_post_read_time or datetime(1900, 1, 1)
        return Post.query.filter_by(recipients=self).filter(
            Post.timestamp > last_read_time).count()

    def haslived(self,house):
       if not self.isliving(house):
        self.lettings.append(house)

    def unlived(self, house):
        if self.isliving(house):
            self.lettings.remove(house)

    def isliving(self, house):
        return self.lettings.filter_by(id=house.id).first()

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<User {}>'.format(self.username)

recipients = db.Table('recipients',
    db.Column('recipient_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id')),
    db.Column('post_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('post.id'))
)

class Post(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'post'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(32))
    body = db.Column(db.String(140))
    timestamp = db.Column(db.DateTime, index=True, default=datetime.utcnow)
    sender_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
    recipients = db.relationship("User",secondary=recipients,lazy="dynamic", backref=db.backref("posts_received",lazy="dynamic"))
    house_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('house.id'))
    __searchable__= ['body']

    def __repr__(self):

        return '<Post {}>'.format(self.body)

    def add_recipient(self, recipient):
        self.recipients.append(recipient)

class Houses(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'house'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True,index=True)    
    address = db.Column(db.String(120))
    postcode = db.Column(db.String(120),index=True)
    licence_holder = db.Column(db.String(140),index=True)    
    __searchable__=['address']
    posts = db.relationship('Post', backref='letting', lazy='dynamic')
    reviews = db.relationship('Review', backref='house', lazy='dynamic')
    checklists = db.relationship('Checklist', backref='house', lazy='dynamic')
    latitude=db.Column(db.Float(precision=32,decimal_return_scale=None),index=True)
    longitude=db.Column(db.Float(precision=30,decimal_return_scale=None),index=True)



    def __repr__(self):
        return '<House {}>'.format(self.address)
```

And you add all the recipients to a post once its uploaded by a different user using list comprehension:

```
Post(body=form.body.data,title=form.title.data,author=current_user,letting=house)
            [post.add_recipient(recipient) for recipient in house.tenants.all()]
            db.session.add(post)
            db.session.commit()
```